# SQLite : LIMIT on a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sqlite, join, subquery, left-join

I have 2 tables in a SQLite file organized as follows:

- *tNode* which contains a node name
- *tItem* which contains a name, a priority, and the reference to its parent node. A node can have multiple items.

To list the nodes and their items, I just have to make a simple JOIN query :

```
SELECT tNode.node, ..., tItem.itemName, tItem.itemPriority, ...
FROM tNode
LEFT JOIN tItem ON tItem.node=tNode.node
ORDER BY tNode.node
```

But now I want the list of the nodes including the item regardless of its priority (**without any duplicate node** in the list). I thought I could use the following query:

```
SELECT tNode.node, ..., tItem2.itemName, tItem2.itemPriority, ...
FROM tNode
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT itemName,itemPriority FROM tItem WHERE tItem.node=tNode.node LIMIT 1)
AS tItem2 ON tItem2.node=tNode.node
ORDER BY tNode.node
```

But this doesn't work ("no such column: tNode.node"). It seems I can't use the tNode.node column in the subquery.

How can I achieve this without having to make one subquery per column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try after removing where clause in subQuery, also LIMIT and adding group by with min

```
SELECT tNode.node, ..., tItem2.itemName, tItem2.itemPriority
FROM tNode
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT itemName,min(itemPriority) as min_priority FROM tItem GROUP BY tItem.node)
AS tItem2 ON tItem2.node=tNode.node
ORDER BY tNode.node
```

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesn't work since the LIMIT 1 in the subquery doesn't return a row where **tItem.node** matches **tNode.node**. It ends up the query returns a node list without item data (except one).

Comment: yes thats correct, i made wrong attempt. your subquery will return 1 result as of limit and then it will join. Resulting only 1 result.Remove LIMIT and use group by instead.Wait I am editing the answer, then try.

Comment: This works however, I need to fetch additional columns from the iItem table. And additionally, I would need to have one row returned from the subquery regardless of its priority.